# Posting Data from an android application to MySql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'am creating a simple application in android which sends data from a form to a mysql database   by php and by using httppost function here is my code in java

```
 public class NouvelUtilisateur extends Activity
{
    EditText username,password,name,lastname,phone,adresse ;
    Button bouton ;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpClient httpclient ;



    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.nouveau);

 username = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.id1) ;
 password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
 name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
 lastname = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.Lastname);
 phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
 adresse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);
 bouton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3) ;

 final String id1 = username.getText().toString();
 final String mdp = password.getText().toString();
 final String prenom = name.getText().toString();
 final String nom = lastname.getText().toString();
 final String tel = phone.getText().toString();
 final String adresse1 = adresse.getText().toString();




 bouton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
     public void onClick(View nouveau)

     {

                  try {
                      httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                      httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.110/nouveau.php");
                      ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", id1));
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", mdp));
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", prenom));
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lastname", nom));
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phone", tel));
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Adresse", adresse1));
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));                   
                   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                   Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
                       }
                       catch(Exception e)
                       {
                           Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
                       }  
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
```

and here is my php code

```
 <?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("agenceimmo");
$username =   $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'] ;
$nom = $_POST['Lastname'] ;
$prenom = $_POST['Name'] ;
$tel = $_POST['Phone'] ; 
$adresse = $_POST['Adresse'] ;
$query_add="INSERT INTO  clients (`id` ,`password` ,`nom` ,`prenom` ,`tel` ,`adresse`)
VALUES ('.$username','.$password', '.$nom','.$prenom','.$tel','.$adresse')";
$query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_close()
?>
```

I really need your help please i can't see any errors

Comment: What errors are you getting, though?

Comment: You should verify that you can POST the data from a script on a different web page and that your .htaccess file is not blocking access. Meaning you should check the server before worrying about Android being a potential problem.

Comment: How can i manipulate the .htaccess file and where can i find it , and how to verify that i can POST the data ??

Answer (score 0):

first, check the permissions you have of both the folder and the file.
Second, go to your root directory and try the following:

```
touch index.html
```

(or index.php), then restart httpd:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: How can i check the permissions ??

Comment: @ziz194 It depends on what operating system that you're running. Your webserver's process needs to have access to the files in its root. Make sure it can serve html and php pages normally.

Comment: yes it can serve php and html normally because i've done a test with a html form and php page that sends the data to the database , so yeah i think that it can serve php and html